# Nested variable assignment in freemarker

Tags: java, json, freemarker

I am using `Freemarker` template engine to create properties file using `json` template.

In this process I am stuck with an issue. I want to get the variable values(one expression within another to get variable value) dynamically.

```
"region"="sys"
"regions[sys]_username" = "abc"
```

Now how to get this in `Freemarker` template?

I am trying something like below:

```
${regions[${region}]_username} but that is not working.
```

But this is throwing error saying we can't use an expression inside another.

Comment: "region"="sys" ,                                                                             "regions[sys]_username" = "abc" , these are in two different lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `region` variable, you can concatenate suffix and use `vars`:

```
<#assign regions = region + "_username">
${.vars[regions]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this.
First "regions[sys]_username" = "abc" has to be changed to "regions_sys_username" = "abc" as square brackets are not supported.

Assume that instanceJSON.value has all the values stored.

```
<#assign getSys=instanceJSON.value.region.replace("\"","")>
<#assign getRegion="instanceJSON.value.regions.${getSys}_username">
regions_sys_username = ${getRegion?eval}
```